# Write into an inputText using actionListener

Tags: jsf, primefaces, actionlistener

i've been recently programming in xhtml using primefaces and jsf; feel a bit noob now; hope you can help me. My first question here.

My problem is: i have an input text then a p:dialog that shows up a panelgrid with 2 columns: one column contain a code and the other column a button. How can i write the selected code into the input text? Use an actionListener on the button? or?

```
<p:inputText id="codice_tributo_1" size="5"></p:inputText>

<p:commandButton id="showDialogButton" type="button" value="Show"
                onclick="PF('dlg').show()" />

            <p:dialog header="Codici" widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true"
                resizable="false">
                <h:form id="form">

                    <p:panelGrid>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel  id="codice1">34567890</p:outputLabel>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-carat-1-w" oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide();"></p:commandButton>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:outputLabel>3twgehrdnftg</p:outputLabel>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-carat-1-w" oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide();"></p:commandButton>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>                

                    </p:panelGrid>


                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to JSF too, but here is what I would try:

1. Bind the value of your `inputText` field to a backing bean.
2. Add an `actionListener` to your `commandButtons`, and use it to call a method on a backing bean, passing in the code as a parameter.
3. In the method, copy the parameter value into the `inputText` field backing value.
4. Add an `update` attribute to your `commandButtons`, and use it to update the `inputText` component.

You might prefer to do this using just JavaScript, similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542406/201891), since there's no reason to communicate with the server.